# display data in listview from selected item in spinner (android , mysql , php)

Tags: php, android, mysql, listview, spinner

I would like to display my list of orders depending on the tables. In my spinner i have the numbers of the tables, now if I select table *n 1* I would like to see in the list view all the orders made by the first table.

```
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Intent showDetails = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Comm.class);
        showDetails.putExtra("N_TABLE", MenuClicked.getInt("N_TABLE"));
        startActivity(showDetails);
        String items = spin.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Log.i("Selected item : ", items);
      }
      @Override
      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
   }
});
```

This is just the part of the code. I know it is incorrect but I don't know what to put there in order for it to work.

I've tried changing it into:

```
spin.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


    /*Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SousMenu.class);
    startActivity(intent);*/

    try {
      JSONObject MenuClicked = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position);
      Intent showDetails = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Comm.class);
      showDetails.putExtra("N_TABLE", MenuClicked.getInt("N_TABLE"));
      startActivity(showDetails);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need an intent.

In your activity keep a reference to your ListView's Adapter as a member variable - I'll call it `mAdapter`.

In your adapter make sure there is an `add(myItem)` method. In `onItemSelected` call `mAdapter.add(myItem)`.

The add() method in the adapter should add the new item into the internally stored list. it should then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` so that the `ListView` is updated.

Comment: i'm getting the data of the listview from MYSQL, i m using a php code where i  pick the value of the  id from the url , i can't use the mAdapter.add(myitem)

Comment: That doesnt make sense with what youve written above. I dont see where PHP fits in what you are doing. Any data you need to use should be in your spinner by this point

Comment: the data is already in the spinner  , using the id i would like to display another data in the lisview but that depends on the id i select in the spinner

Answer (score 0):

Please forgive me if this isn't what you wanted. Trying to help but as I'm new to stack overflow I can't make comments yet.

From what I understand of your question you have a spinner with a list of tables. When you select a value from the spinner a query is ran on an online database and returned to you all the orders for said table. If my understanding is correct then I recommend you return a json object, loop through said object adding the orders to the listview with the mAdapter.add(myitem) as Nick wrote.